# How to override max-width value in media screen query using PrimeNg menubar?

Tags: css, overriding, media-queries, primeng

In my Angular project, I'm using PrimeNG components.

In my angular.json file I have the following lines

```
"styles": [
           "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
           "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
           "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
           "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
           "src/styles.scss",
          ],
```

I have a p-menubar in my header page that becomes a "hamburger menu" when the screen's width below to 960px. So I noticed this media query in theme.css :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .p-menubar {
```

So I say Ok, let's modify 960px in 600px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .p-menubar {
```

I save the theme.css file and run "ng serve" again but when I inspect with chrome's developer tools (F12), I always see 960px in the theme.css.

My initial question is : Is it possible to override the value of "max-width" in media query and keep the same CSS rules without redefining a custom CSS with all the rules that already stand for 960px ? If so, how ?

By chance, I found a workaround but I don't even understand why it works.

In angular.json, I added "src/custom-styles.scss"

```
"styles": [
           "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
           "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
           "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
           "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
           "src/styles.scss",
           "src/custom-styles.scss",
          ],
```

The custom-styles.scss is completely empty. I let 600px in the media query of my theme.css file. I run "ng serve" again and here it is ! I see 600px in the media query of my theme.css file.

IF someone could explain me the reasons for this, i would be so grateful

Comment: I'm stuck in the same situation.  Why would they hard-code "960px" instead of defining a variable and allowing us to override the value of that variable?  My guess is that caching came into play for you.  I don't think you should modify "theme.css" in the node_modules folder.  If you update or reinstall packages, your changes will be lost.  I found a similar question and answer here: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=72635.  But it's just redefining the CSS from the theme.  This is just baffling.  Hopefully it's something simple that we're just missing.